# ヤマトナデシコ七変化 translation

Tags: set-phrases

What is the meaning of this phrase? I understand the lady and kabuki references but overall, what is it trying to say?

Answer (score 3):

ヤマトナデシコ「大和撫子」means a woman who displays feminine virtues of old Japan. 七変化「しちへんげ」is a kabuki dance in which the dancer quickly changes his clothes seven times.

I think it points at the metamorphosis Sunako has to undergo, in order to become a beautiful lady.